# ftp upload not working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ftp

I am trying to upload files from a local folder to a ftp server folder which works fine when doing it with filezilla.
I keep getting this error:

Quote:
the remote server returned an error: (550) file unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
Code:

'....ftppath = "tp://192.xxx.xx.xx/%2f/feedb/gnip/

```
      Public Sub uploadFTP(ByVal ftpPath As String, ByVal localPath As String, 
           ByVal username As String, ByVal psswd As String)
      Dim item As String = String.Empty
      item = "F20110210022920.xml"
      Try
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(localPath & item)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        fs.Close()


        Dim clsRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(ftpPath & item), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, psswd)
        clsRequest.KeepAlive = False
        clsRequest.Proxy = Nothing
        clsRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        clsRequest.Timeout = 10000
        Dim bFile() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(localPath & item)
        Dim clsStream As Stream = clsRequest.GetRequestStream()
        clsStream.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length)
        clsStream.Close()
        clsStream.Dispose()


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved issue...

```
clsrequest.usepassive = true
frequest.usebinary = false
```

and included subfolder in ftp path

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but i do have a method you can use to find the answer ... download and install a packet sniffer and watch the ftp traffic. the control channel conversation shouldn't be hard to follow. see what the difference is between your conversation and filezilla's conversation and you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, grab a copy of WireShark and inspect the packets being sent by FileZilla and your custom client. From here you'll be able to inspect the working request and the non-working request.  From analyzing the differences, you should be able to determine what you need to fix to get things working.

Comment: can i just use fiddler? ok nevermind I guess that is for http requests onlt